# Trouble compiling libpng (& zlib) using RVCT 4.0's armcc compiler

Tags: cygwin, arm, libpng

I'm trying to compile libpng & zlib using the RVCT 4.0 armcc compiler. However armcc cannot find 'fcntl.h', which I assume is a standard C library. Cygwin has fcntl.h (and the associated files types.h and _types.h), but when I use those, I get various compilation errors.

Should I be using Cygwin's version of standard C libraries, or RVCT's? If the latter is correct, where do I get RVCT's versions of fcntl.h, types.h and _types.h?

Thanks!
Arjun

Answer (score 0):

Which version of zlib/libpng are you trying to compile?
fcntl.h is POSIX standard, not ANSI/ISO C. RealView doesn't care about POSIX.
Compiling the zlib with RVCT 4.0 has always worked like a breeze.
I've tried libpng: well, it works if you define RISCOS, to prevent the sources from including  sys/types.h (yet another POSIX file).
Here's my command line: armcc -c *.c -I/tmp/zlib/ -DRISCOS

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Ron,

I posted this same question to the png-mng-implement mail list and they helped me through it.

I initially removed all the gz* files in zlib (they need fcntl.h), so the dependency on fcntl.h was resolved. However I ran into another problem where zconf.h wanted sys/types.h. To fix this I manually edited zconf.h to make sure it didn't include types.h.

Thanks anyway for your help!
Arjun